# How to pass the existing silverlight object from parent to child window using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, silverlight, window, parent

We have a Silverlight map on the page. The task is to open it in the child browser window and turn it back on close. One of the demands was to keep this map singleton or a kind of that. 
Thank you for the help.

We have this kind of an object. It draws the map.

```
<object type="application/x-silverlight" data="data:application/x-silverlight," id="wxMapObj" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="background" value="white">
<param name="enableGPUAcceleration" value="true">
<param name="enablehtmlaccess" value="true">
<param name="autoUpgrade" value="true">
<param name="windowless" value="true">
<param name="source" value="/Optima/...">
<param name="initParams" value="config=/Optima/...,scriptId=wxMap,scriptInit=onWxMapLoading">
<param name="onError" value="__slEvent0">
</object>
```

I'm doing var wnd = window.open(...);
And I need to set this object into DOM of child window. I wonder if it really is possible.

Comment: Can you please provide some more detail and post some code that you have so far? It is also unclear to me exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Is it more clear now?